# Help with PDOException and hook_schema()

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to set up an install file for a custom module that I'm creating but having a little trouble when Drupal tries to create my tables.

It's probably a simple syntax error but can't track it down at all. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL, `logo_url` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL, `url` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMM' at line 3: CREATE TABLE {survey_compare_companies} ( `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'The primary key for this table.', `company_name` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL, `logo_url` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL, `url` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The company’s website address.', `int_url` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'URL to the Survey Compare page for this company', `payment_per_survey` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The payment amount per survey', `min_payout` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The minimum amount required to qualify for a payout', `ave_survey_length` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The average length of individual surveys', `ref_bonus` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The bonus offered for referrals', `other_bonus` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Details of other bonuses', `age_id` INT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the age group that this company offers surveys to', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'Holds details for various survey companies'; Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2717 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\database\database.inc).
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_schema()
*/

function survey_compare_schema() {

    $schema = array();

    $schema['survey_compare_companies'] = array(

        'description' => 'Holds details for various survey companies',

        'fields' => array(

            'id' => array(
                'description'   => 'The primary key for this table.',
                'type'          => 'serial',
                'unsigned'      => TRUE,
                'not null'      => TRUE
            ),

            'company_name' => array(
                'description'   => 'The name of the company.',
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'logo_url' => array(
                'description'   => "A URL to the company's logo",
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'url' => array(
                'description'   => "The company's website address.",
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'int_url' => array(
                'description'   => 'URL to the Survey Compare page for this company',
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'payment_per_survey' => array(
                'description'   => 'The payment amount per survey',
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'min_payout' => array(
                'description'   => 'The minimum amount required to qualify for a payout',
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'ave_survey_length' => array(
                'description'   => 'The average length of individual surveys',
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'ref_bonus' => array(
                'description'   => 'The bonus offered for referrals',
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'other_bonus' => array(
                'description'   => 'Details of other bonuses',
                'type'          => 'varchar'
            ),

            'age_id' => array(
                'description'   => 'The ID of the age group that this company offers surveys to',
                'type'          => 'int'
            )

        ),

        'primary key' => array('id')

    );

$schema['survey_compare_payment_types'] = array(

    'description' => 'Holds details about the types of payment offered',

    'fields' => array(

        'id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The primary key for this table.',
            'type'          => 'serial',
            'unsigned'      => TRUE,
            'not null'      => TRUE
        ),

        'name' => array(
            'description'   => 'The name of this payment type',
            'type'          => 'varchar'
        )

    )

);

$schema['survey_compare_companies_payment_types_relation'] = array(

    'description' => 'Specifies links between companies and the payment types that they offer',

    'fields' => array(

        'id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The primary key for this table.',
            'type'          => 'serial',
            'unsigned'      => TRUE,
            'not null'      => TRUE
        ),

        'company_id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The ID of the company',
            'type'          => 'int'
        ),

        'payment_type_id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The ID of the payment type',
            'type'          => 'int'
        )

    )

);

$schema['survey_compare_min_age'] = array(

    'description' => 'Specifies the minimum age required to fill in surveys for this company',

    'fields' => array(

        'id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The primary key for this table.',
            'type'          => 'serial',
            'unsigned'      => TRUE,
            'not null'      => TRUE
        ),

        'min_age' => array(
            'description'   => 'The minimum age',
            'type'          => 'int'
        )

    )

);

$schema['survey_compare_payment_options'] = array(

    'description' => 'Specifies the payment options available',

    'fields' => array(

        'id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The primary key for this table.',
            'type'          => 'serial',
            'unsigned'      => TRUE,
            'not null'      => TRUE
        ),

        'name' => array(
            'description'   => 'The name of this payment option',
            'type'          => 'varchar'
        ),

        'logo_url' => array(
            'description'   => 'The URL to the logo for this payment option',
            'type'          => 'varchar'
        )

    )

);

$schema['survey_compare_companies_payment_options_relation'] = array(

    'description' => 'Specifies links between companies and the payment options that they offer',

    'fields' => array(

        'id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The primary key for this table.',
            'type'          => 'serial',
            'unsigned'      => TRUE,
            'not null'      => TRUE
        ),

        'company_id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The ID of the company',
            'type'          => 'int'
        ),

        'option_id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The ID of the payment option',
            'type'          => 'int'
        )

    )

);

$schema['survey_compare_countries'] = array(

    'description' => 'Specifies countries for use with this module',

    'fields' => array(

        'id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The primary key for this table.',
            'type'          => 'serial',
            'unsigned'      => TRUE,
            'not null'      => TRUE
        ),

        'name' => array(
            'description'   => 'The name of the country',
            'type'          => 'varchar'
        ),

        'country_code' => array(
            'description'   => 'The country code',
            'type'          => 'varchar'
        )

    )

);

$schema['survey_compare_companies_countries_relation'] = array(

    'description' => 'Specifies links between companies and the countries that they cover',

    'fields' => array(

        'id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The primary key for this table.',
            'type'          => 'serial',
            'unsigned'      => TRUE,
            'not null'      => TRUE
        ),

        'company_id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The ID of the company',
            'type'          => 'int'
        ),

        'country_id' => array(
            'description'   => 'The ID of the country',
            'type'          => 'int'
        )

    )

);

return $schema;

}
```

I've tried reading the error but without seeing the whole statement, I'm ha

Comment: save yourself the headache (because I cant see if offhand either ...). Make this table + fields in MySQL using PHPMYADMIN or whatever Admin UI tool you want. Then install in the [Schema](http://www.drupal.org/project/schema) and copy and paste the `$schema` definition it gives you for this table in the drupal admin area. It will take you 5 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` is required for `varchar` columns...

All tables except the first are missing a primary key, as well. Also, adding some indexes will probably save you some performance problems down the line.